# Algorithms for Polynomials Over a Real Algebraic Number Field, a reference

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computer-science, computer-algebra, field-extensions

I need to find "Algorithms for Polynomials Over a Real Algebraic Number Field
Ph.D. thesis, University of Wisconsin, Madison (1974) by Rubald". However I cannot find it online nor in my university library, even though it seems to be quite a popular reference in the field (eg. Collins and McCallum often cite it).

> **Question.** Could someone point me to a similar reference or even better
> where to find Rubald's Ph.D. thesis?

I'm especially interested in the efficient algorithms for the arithmetic operations in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: See also the 1990 paper, “arithmetic with real algebraic numbers is in NC”: https://cs.nyu.edu/mishra/PUBLICATIONS/90.p120-mishra.pdf

Comment: Thank you, nice reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thesis can be found [here](https://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/pub/techreports/1974/TR206.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much